# Jython override method with same name

Tags: java, python, jython

I saw a similar problem occurred on JRuby back in 2010 when we would try to override in Jruby a method that was overloaded orginally on the java source code. How do we deal with this in Jython? More specifically, how can i specify for one of the methods that are overloaded to be override and ignore the remaining or how can I override all of them?

Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to call an overloaded method, or define one in Python?

Comment: I am trying  to call a specific method that was overloaded in Java and I am overriding in Jython.

Answer (score 1):

Python does not support method overloading (but it does support default values).

```
def my_function(paramA, paramB = None):
  pass
```

Since Jython is merely a Python implementation, I belive the same stands true.

Comment: right..could you go into a little more details on how could I use the default values to specify which overloaded method then? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To call a specific Java method from Jython, you may have to make the types match very closely, or even exactly.

Jython does some [type coercion](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonAndJavaIntegration.html), but there are situations in which this does not select the the method you want.

To call public methods on specific base classes you can use `BaseClass.method(self, ...)`.  To call protected methods you must [prefix](http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/subclassing.html) the method name like `self.super__method(...)`.